# Is there a value that appears exactly at one point?

Tags: analysis, maxima-minima

Let $S^2$ be the surface of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and let $T\colon S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous map.

We have that $T$ gets a maximum $T_{\text{max}}$ and a minimum $T_{\text{min}}$ and that there is a point $x_0\in S^2$ with $T(x_0)=T(-x_0)$.

I want to check if there is value $T\in (T_{\text{min}}, T_{\text{max}})$ that appears at exactly one point on $S^2$.

So, for $h\neq 0$ we want to check if there is a point $x$ such that $f(x)=T(x)-T(x+h)$ has exactly one root, right?

To show that there is at least one root to we use the intermediate value theorem?

But how can we conclude that there is exactly one root? Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Can you clarify?  "...if there is a point $x$ such that $f(x)$ has exactly one root" doesn't make sense.

Comment: The constant map $x \mapsto 47$ is continuous, and has no value that appears at exactly one point.  Of course, this makes the question of antipodal points with the same value much easier, but suggests that your approach may be flawed...

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not.  If $f:S^2\to\mathbb R$ is defined by $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_3$, then $T_{max}=1=-T_{min}$, and for any $T\in (T_{\text{min}}, T_{\text{max}})$, we have 
$$f^{-1}(\{T\})=\{(x_1,x_2,T):x_1^2+x_2^2=1-T^2\}$$
is a cicle, hence has infinitely many points.

Now if you ask for $T\in [T_{\text{min}}, T_{\text{max}}]$, things change.

Comment: How did you get $f^{-1}(\{T\})$ ?

Comment: Certainly $f(x_1,x_2,T)=T$.  If $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=T$, then $x_3=T$.  The condition $x_1^2+x_2^2=1-T^2$ just means that $(x_1,x_2,T)\in S^2$.

Comment: Ah I see!! And since there are many points $(x_1, x_2)$ that satisfy that equation, there cannot be a value $T$ that appears exactly once, right?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.